# Rails 3.0.3, rails_admin gem, generator not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting error installing Rails_admin with rails 3.0.3. Command line log shown below -

```
    C:\rorprj\app>gem uninstall rails_admin 
    Successfully uninstalled rails_admin-0.0.0


    C:\rorprj\app>gem install rails_admin 
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...  
    Successfully installed rails_admin-0.0.0 1 gem installed  
    Installing ri documentation for rails_admin-0.0.0...  
    Installing RDoc documentation for rails_admin-0.0.0...


    C:\rorprj\app>rails generate rails_admin:install_admin 
    **Could not find generator rails_admin:install_admin.**

    C:\rorprj\app>rails -v 
    Rails 3.0.3
```

Anything I can do fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
```

Sometimes the actual github repo has an different version. I have it running on 3.0.3 and that is what is in my gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

If you call

```
rails generate rails_admin
```

the 'help' returns

*Hello, to install rails_admin into your app you need to ru*n:

```
rake rails_admin:install
```

And this works. I just encountered the same problem as you. (Keep in mind that you need to add the gem to the gemfile too)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this gem to your `Gemfile`? This file is responsible for loading all gems that your application depends on, and if this gem isn't specified in it then it will not be loaded.